# как игнорировать любые символы кроме символов типа int при вводе элементов во вложенном списке

Tags: python

```
N = int(input("Введите количество списков в списке:"))
arr = [list(map(int, input("Введите числа во вложенном списке:").split())) 
       for i in range (N)] 
print(arr)
res = list(map(max, zip(*arr)))
print(res)
```

Comment: хотелось бы увидеть результат в программе когда допустим я ввожу элементы -34 gh 87 56 у меня 'gh' игнорировалось,причём ввод нужен не по одному элементу,а сразу все элементы должны вводиться и тогда бы сработало исключение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

prompt = "Введите числа во вложенном списке:"
arr = [list(map(int, re.findall(r'((?:\+|\-)?\d+)', input(prompt)))) 
       for i in range (N)]
```

---

```
Введите числа во вложенном списке:1 2 3
Введите числа во вложенном списке:-10 aaa 34 bbb -123
Введите числа во вложенном списке:-4 +5 blah-blah 6

In [14]: arr
Out[14]: [[1, 2, 3], [-10, 34, -123], [-4, 5, 6]]
```

---

`re.findall()` - функция поиска всех вхождений, удовлетворяющим регулярному выражению (`Regular Expression` AKA `RegEx`)

`r'((?:\+|\-)?\d+)'` - шаблон для выборки всех чисел, которые могут, но не обязаны иметь знак (`+` или `-`) перед числом

Comment: re.sub(r'[^\d\s-]', '' объясните пожалуйста эту конструкцию

Comment: я уже заметил хотел вам сообщить)

Comment: @MaxU что такое `(N)`

Comment: я могу ответить вместо MaxU,N - это кол-во списков в списке

Comment: @S.Nick, да, N берётся из вопроса

Comment: @Noob_Prog, не понял вопрос. Можете привести пример строки?

Comment: (?:\+|\-) в этой скобке не захватываются фрагменты (+ или -) отдельно от цифры не выводятся в результат поиска,затем выполняется вторая скобка ((?:\+|\-)?\d+) знак ? означает что - или + может быть одним \d означает что может быть любая цифра,а + имея своё спец.значение,что цифр может быть сколько угодно?

Comment: arr = [list(map(int, re.findall(r'((?:\+|\-)?\d+)', input(prompt)))) 
       for i in range (N)]

Comment: [подробный разбор RegEx - здесь](https://regex101.com/r/gy9EI2/1/),  там же можно поиграться с разными строками

Comment: ну а я правильно объяснил шаблон?

Comment: "?" - обозначает что то, что стоит перед ним может встретиться 0 или 1 раз. Т.е. __необязательный__ знак перед числом. В остальном вроде бы правильно

Comment: @Max U что делает r'?

Comment: @Noob_Prog, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals